# fetching string from database in php only returns part before a space

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i am trying to display a varchar(40) from database to php page field. the value in database is "test address" but when it displays on page it only shows "test".

Below is the code, appreciate you help.

```
$sql = "SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,CITY,STATE,ZIP FROM user WHERE USER_ID='$id'";
$result = $database->query($sql);   
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    $_SESSION['fname']=ucfirst(strtolower($row[0]));        
    $_SESSION['lname']=ucfirst(strtolower($row[1]));
    $_SESSION['address']=$row[2];

<input type='text' name='street_address'DISABLED  size='75' value=";echo var_dump($_SESSION['address']);  print" />
```

Comment: You need to show us the SQL statement.

Comment: u mean quotes on echo statement? i thought u dont need quotes while echoing variables

Comment: I mean quotes around the html field value="" of the input tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are probably missing the quotes around the value. Can you paste the view source?

But, try this:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='street_address'DISABLED  size='75' value='";
echo var_dump($_SESSION['address']);
echo "' />";
```